# url rewriting in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I was using this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jukson/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

to remove index.php from codeigniter url in my wamp.

but I have now installed windows 8 dev. preview and wamp does not run very well in this OS. So i have installed apache, mysql, php manually. All is well except that above code doesn't remove "index.php" from url and without index.php the page does not open.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the duplicated line `RewriteEngine On` - leave only the first one.
Also, although your pages should not load at all if mod rewrite would be disabled (you should get an error 500 page having this `.htaccess`), try checking if it is enabled.
My advice is that is always a good idea to check the error log.